# How to speed up slow (.6s) mask assignment in Python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, computer-vision

I am trying to visualize a binary mask of an image in python by overlaying the masked pixels on the image. The image dimensions are 360 by 640 pixels. My visualization is running really slow (.6 seconds per mask) and I timed my code and pinned the bottle neck to converting the binary mask into a color mask that I can add to the image. I have tried to do this a couple of ways.

First I tried a list comprehension:

```
color_mask = [[[50,50,50] if val == 1 else [0,0,0] for val in mask_row] for mask_row in mask]
```

and it runs in about .6 seconds

Then I tried using a mask assignment on a numpy array and it ran in about 1.2 seconds (surprisingly slower)

```
color_mask = np.zeros(shape=(image.shape))
color_mask[output_dict["detection_masks"][0]] = [50,50,50]
```

After the color mask is generated I add it to the original image to visualize the mask on the image. I want to be able to run this visualization in real time with up to 20 masks.

Why is the mask assignment and list comprehension so slow? How can I speed one of them up?

You can build a mask for testing like this:

```
mask = np.zeros(shape=(563,750,1))
mask[50:200,50:200,:] = 1
```

Comment: can you post a testable fragment of your `mask` ?

Comment: ```mask = np.zeros(shape=(563,750,1))
mask[50:200,50:200,:] = 1``` You can use that as a test mask. The masks I am using are coming out of mask-rcnn from tensorflow, so it isn't easy to get the part of the code running on a new machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found using numpy to do this is more performant

Without seeing the data you're working with I generate a random binary image

```py
import numpy as np
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(360, 640, 1))
color_mask = np.array([50,50,50]) * mask + np.array([0,0,0]) * (1 - mask) # you do not need the second half of this statement if you're setting to all zeros
```

Using list comprehension the time was on average 0.280 seconds

Using numpy the time was on average 0.015 seconds

Removing the second half of the statement yielded times of around 0.004 seconds

Comment: This is way faster thanks! Do you have any idea why doing a mask assignment is so much slower? Or why a list comprehension is so much slower?

Comment: @AlexMussell Using a list comprehension requires creating a dynamic list while iterating through all the values, which can be slow. NumPy is doing matrix operations, across static matrices, which it is very optimized to do.